# java.sql.sqlexpcetion:ORA-00917:missing comma

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am sorry that i ask a very stupid question but i cant find the place where i miss the comma in the code..

```
sqlStr.append("INSERT INTO DS_GOAL ");
sqlStr.append("(DS_SITE_CODE, DS_FINANCIAL_YEAR, DS_DEPARTMENT_CODE, DS_PLAN_ID, DS_GOAL_ID, ");
sqlStr.append("DS_DESC, TO_CHAR(DS_PLAN_END_DATE, \"dd/MM/YY\"),");
sqlStr.append("DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE, DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE_OTHER, DS_FOCUS, DS_FOCUS_OTHER, ");
sqlStr.append("DS_TOTAL, DS_EQUIPMENT, DS_RECRUIT, DS_FTE, ");
sqlStr.append("DS_CREATED_USER, DS_MODIFIED_USER, DS_GOAL_ORDER ) ");
sqlStr.append("VALUES ");
sqlStr.append("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,");
sqlStr.append("?, ?,");
sqlStr.append("?, ?, ?, ?,");
sqlStr.append("?, ?, ?, ?,");
sqlStr.append("?, ?, ?)");
sqlStr_insertGoal = sqlStr.toString();
```

After the
    sqlStr.toString()

the console shows

```
 INSERT INTO DS_GOAL (DS_SITE_CODE, DS_FINANCIAL_YEAR, DS_DEPARTMENT_CODE, DS_PLAN_ID,
 DS_GOAL_ID, 
 DS_DESC, TO_CHAR(DS_PLAN_END_DATE, 'dd/MM/YYYY'), 
 DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE, DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE_OTHER, DS_FOCUS, DS_FOCUS_OTHER, 
 DS_TOTAL, DS_EQUIPMENT, DS_RECRUIT,
 DS_FTE, DS_CREATED_USER, DS_MODIFIED_USER, DS_GOAL_ORDER)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?)
```

After Edited the code
the console shows

```
INSERT INTO DS_GOAL (DS_SITE_CODE, DS_FINANCIAL_YEAR, DS_DEPARTMENT_CODE, DS_PLAN_ID,
 DS_GOAL_ID, 
 DS_DESC, DS_PLAN_END_DATE, 
 DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE, DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE_OTHER, DS_FOCUS, DS_FOCUS_OTHER, 
 DS_TOTAL, DS_EQUIPMENT, DS_RECRUIT,
 DS_FTE, DS_CREATED_USER, DS_MODIFIED_USER, DS_GOAL_ORDER)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, TO_CHAR(DS_PLAN_END_DATE, 'dd/MM/YYYY'),?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?,
 ?,?, ?, ?)
```

But the consoles shows invalid column index error
Thanks for help

Comment: format your code first it's unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem isn't actually a case of a missing comma (in my experience ORA errors are notorious for telling you the wrong thing). My suspicion is that your real issue is the use of `"` around the format string in your `TO_CHAR` call. To demonstrate, try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, "dd/MM/YY")
  FROM DUAL;
```

If I run the above I get an `ORA-00904: "dd/MM/YY": invalid identifier` error. If I change the quotes to apostrophes instead:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/MM/YY')
  FROM DUAL;
```

I get `16/04/14`. Double quotes are for identifiers, not strings:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/MM/YY') AS "The Date"
  FROM DUAL;                        // ^ This is an identifier
```

prints:

```
The Date
--------
16/04/14
```

### EDIT:

Sorry, I should have spotted this one sooner! You're using `TO_CHAR` in your columns list, which you can't do. The below example nicely produces an `ORA-00917: missing comma` error:

```
CREATE TABLE JON_TEST (COL1 VARCHAR2(20));

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO JON_TEST (TO_CHAR(COL1, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
VALUES (SYSDATE);
```

Whereas this works:

```
INSERT INTO JON_TEST (COL1)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/MM/YYYY'));
```

So you need to correct **three** things:

- You need to change `TO_CHAR` to `TO_DATE`, and
- You need to move the call to `TO_DATE` to your `VALUES` clause, and
- You need to ensure that you use `'` instead of `"` with the format string.

This is how [Oracle define the syntax for `INSERT` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm):

[image: This is how Oracle defines the syntax for INSERT statements]

Notice that in the middle section that it only says `column_name` and not `sql_expression`.

Try changing your query to the following:

```
sqlStr.append("INSERT INTO DS_GOAL ")
    .append("(DS_SITE_CODE, DS_FINANCIAL_YEAR, DS_DEPARTMENT_CODE, DS_PLAN_ID, DS_GOAL_ID, ")
    .append("DS_DESC, DS_PLAN_END_DATE, ")
    .append("DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE, DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE_OTHER, DS_FOCUS, DS_FOCUS_OTHER, ")
    .append("DS_TOTAL, DS_EQUIPMENT, DS_RECRUIT, DS_FTE, ")
    .append("DS_CREATED_USER, DS_MODIFIED_USER, DS_GOAL_ORDER ) ")
    .append("VALUES ")
    .append("(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,")
    .append("?, TO_DATE(?, 'dd/MM/YY'),")
    .append("?, ?, ?, ?,")
    .append("?, ?, ?, ?,")
    .append("?, ?, ?)");
    sqlStr_insertGoal = sqlStr.toString();
```

Comment: @user3340095 If you could print out `sqlStr.toString();` to the console and add it to the question, it may help.

Comment: INSERT INTO DS_GOAL 
     (DS_SITE_CODE, DS_FINANCIAL_YEAR, DS_DEPARTMENT_CODE,
      DS_PLAN_ID, DS_GOAL_ID, 
DS_DESC,  TO_CHAR(DS_PLAN_END_DATE, 'dd/MM/YYYY'),  DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE, DS_CORP_OBJECTIVE_OTHER, DS_FOCUS, DS_FOCUS_OTHER, DS_TOTAL, DS_EQUIPMENT, DS_RECRUIT, DS_FTE, DS_CREATED_USER, DS_MODIFIED_USER, DS_GOAL_ORDER) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?)

Comment: @user3340095 Please see the revised answer - sorry, I should have caught that one sooner. This is a perfect case-in-point for my comment about poor Oracle error messages!

Comment: This will cause invalid column index error
Thanks for help indeed!!

Comment: @user3340095 You moved the column name out to the values clause, the column name needed to stay where it was, it was the `TO_DATE` that had to move - see the code I posted for what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for help!!
I would like to ask what format should I input for the    DS_PLAN_END_DATE?
since the consoles shows     invalid number
when I type the date eg:10/01/2015

Comment: @user3340095 What is the datatype of the `DS_PLAN_END_DATE` column?

Comment: the datatype in the database is DATE

Comment: @user3340095 Then you need to use `TO_DATE` instead of `TO_CHAR`

Comment: Finally it works!!
Thanks for helping me to clarify my mistakes. I am very appreciated for your patience!!